Greetings in American English
The old fashioned greeting "How do you do?" This is still very commonly used in American English. Is the correct response "I do well, how do you do?" I hear this frequently.

Where are you hearing this frequently?

Voted to close this as a duplicate. This answer is (in my experience) correct about American English.

One comment in the earlier thread: 'Nobody in America uses "How do you do?" '
